# Retrieve column 4 from Column 2 and 3 which contains minimum and maximum conditions along with Column 1 which is a separate value?

Tags: excel, indexing, match, ms-office, vlookup

Hello I have a table shown below where I have letters in column 1, and min and max ranges for column 2 and 3. I am trying to retrieve the final number in column 4.

I know I can use a VLOOKUP and set the range as TRUE to get the last column. However, how would I factor in multiple columns/criteria to find match the correct range with the correct letter.

For example, I can would like to get value 4 from the last column. I would have to match with "B" and it would be between 0 and $50,000.

```
A   0            $50,000    1
A   $50,001      $100,000    2
A   $100,001     $250,000    3
B   0            $50,000    4
B   $50,001      $100,000    5
B   $100,001     $250,000    6
C   0            $50,000    7
C   $50,001      $100,000    8
C   $100,001     $250,000    9
```

Thank you!

Comment: Title should have said retrieving column 4 from matching columns 1,2,3 - Sorry!

Comment: Are the return values always numbers?

Comment: Are the patterns always the same: 0, 50001,100001?

Comment: And you can [edit] the post to change the title.

Comment: This is just a short snippet of my larger chart, so the range goes all the way to 999,999,999. And the the return values are always numbers (factors in my real table).

Comment: But are the patterns the same do they always break at the same dollar amounts or do those vary based on column A?

Comment: Same deal as a `vlookup` but instead use a multi-criteria `Index/Match` function.

Comment: They break off at the same, however it goes up in various amounts. 0 - 50001 - 100001 - 250001 - 500001.

Comment: Can you please writer the format of the Index/Match - I've been trying but I don't seem to be having any luck all day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways:

If the pattern is the same as to the breaks of the dollar amounts then use this:

```
=INDEX(D:D,MATCH(G1,A:A,0)+MATCH(H1,$B$1:$B$3)-1)
```

Where `MATCH(G1,A:A,0)` returns the first row where the ID is located and `MATCH(H1,$B$1:$B$3)` finds the relative location of the price in the first pattern.  Change `$B$1:$B$3` to encompass the whole pattern.

If the patterns are different then you can use this:

```
=SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,G1,B:B,"<=" & H1,C:C,">=" & H1)
```

[image]

---

One more for the future when Microsoft releases `FILTER()`:

```
=FILTER(D:D,(A:A=G1)*(B:B<=H1)*(C:C>=H1))
```

This is entered normally and does not matter the pattern.

Comment: WOW this is awesome, thank you! I'm curious... why did you only set the second match range to only the initial first set and not the entire thing (B1 to B3 in your example as opposed to B1 to B9)

Comment: @BrowniesAtNight we add the where it lands in the pattern to the row in which the first match was found.  If we did the whole we would get the wrong output as the second match would not return the correct position.